# Can't get Jersey JAX-RS Resource working with Proguard-obfuscated REST service

Tags: jersey, proguard

Please excuse the length of this posting. I am trying to get all of the useful information in it and anticipate questions people might have.

I have a series of RESTful web services that have been implemented with Jersey and running in Jetty.
**Everything works fine with the un-obfuscated version of the jar file.** But when I obfuscate with Proguard I get a 500 error with the message

```
The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

As part of my package I have an extremely simple ping service just so I can test connectivity and the basic Jersey configuration.

My code that starts up jetty with jersey looks like this:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.sw.pr.hq");
sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass",
            "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/pr");
sch.addServlet(sh, "/");
```

When I try to hit my ping url from a browser the debug log shows the following lines:

```
Jan 13, 2011 9:33:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
[java] INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
[java]   com.sw.pr.hq
```

So I am of the opinion that jetty is configured and running correctly. Like I said, the un-obfuscated version of this application works fine.

The stack trace that appears when I try to ping appears at the bottom of this posting, but the most troubling line is:

```
[java] SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[java] 2011-01-13 09:33:35.585:WARN:/pr:unavailable
```

My proguard configuration looks like this (comments removed for brevity). Note that when I do a jar -tvf obfuscated.jar call I see the class com.sw.pr.HQServerResource.class file there.

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses com.sw.rtm
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.properties,**.png,**.css
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-keep public class * {
    public *;
}
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

My ping resource class looks like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class HQServerResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/ping")
    public PingResponse pingGet(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        LOGGER.debug("pingGet()");
        return getPingResponse(httpRequest);
    }
}
```

Now I will enter into my speculation phase due to my unfamiliarity with Proguard.

I am of the opinion that my problem boils down to Proguard mashing my @Path annotations in my class file. But I have the directive (-keepattributes *Annotation*) in my proguard configuration file. Hence I am now lost.

**Any guidance would be appreciated.**

STACK TRACE:

[java] com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:103)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1182)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$600(WebApplicationImpl.java:161)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:698)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:438)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:287)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:587)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:213)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:342)
[java]     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:516)
[java]     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
[java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:431)
[java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:330)
[java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:510)

Comment: Hi jspyeatt!
I've used your ServletHolder portion of code to create programmatically a Jersey Servlet with Jetty embedded webserver on Android.
Unfortunately I'm getting the exception:
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
Do you have any idea how to solve this? THANKS!

Answer (score 10):

I believe I have tracked down the problem I was having.
The issue is that proguard, by default, doesn't include the directory entries in the obfuscated jar file.

So my obfuscated jar file contents looked something like this.

```
com/sw/pr/hq/HQServerResource.class
com/sw/pr/hq/a.class
com/sw/pr/hq/a.class
```

Note, no directory entries.

when I add the **-keepdirectories** directive to my proguard file my obfuscated jar file looks like this.

```
com/
com/sw/
com/sw/pr/
com/sw/pr/hq/
com/sw/pr/hq/HQServerResource.class
com/sw/pr/hq/a.class
com/sw/pr/hq/a.class
```

When this is done, Servlet is able to traverse the directories looking for my @Path annotated resources.

One bloody directive, days of pain.